# コンバーターを自作したい

Tags: filesystems

psdやpdfをPNG変換、動画ではmovをmp4にする等のメディアコンバーターはどういう原理で作られているのでしょうか？ネットで調べるとよく広告だらけのフリーコンバーターが出てきますが、そんなに簡単に作れるものなんでしょうか。

Comment: 簡単に作れるかどうかではなく、広告収入が開発費を上回る（見込みがあった）から開発されたのでは？

Answer (score 1):

例えば動画・音声ファイル向けには [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) 、画像ファイルなら [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) などの (フリーで使える) 変換ツールが存在します。
ただしこれらは基本的にコマンドラインで操作するので、慣れていないユーザーには扱いにくいため、内部で FFmpeg 等を呼び出す GUI アプリも多数存在します。(HandBrake, Xmedia Recode 等)

オンライン上でファイルを変換できるものも、恐らくは上記のような変換ツールを裏で使用しているものと思われます。

「ファイルを別の形式に変換する」仕組みを一から作るのは難しいですが、「ファイルを受け取って既存のツールで変換する」であれば、多少は簡単に作れるかもしれません。

**参考:**
[FFmpeg APIで、さまざまな動画を操る - 前編](https://codezine.jp/article/detail/2444)